# Generating electrical current using sea or ocean currents

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, power, ions

I'm curious to know is this concept can work.

Place two metallic plates in a body of salt water. Connect a power supply in order to attract ions close to each plate. Place two coils as illustrated around the plates. Create a water flow (could be sea waves or sea currents).

The ions will be dragged by the water flow and will generate a magnetic field which in turn should generate a current in the coils.

Could this concept be used to generate power?

[image: Sea Water Current Generator]

Comment: There is a current anyway because of the power supply, the ions will be taken off to sea and new ones will replace them with the energy supplied by the power source.

Comment: The main idea is to generate more energy than we put. both anode an cathode can be insulated by a super thin sheet of mylar. I just need a way to figure out how to get the positive ions only to go through one coil and the negative ones through the other in order not to cancel their effects.

Comment: The way I see it, ions flowing away are irrelevant for the current in the power supply set up. For the set up it makes no difference if ions leave on the right  because it will generate new ones in the neutral water comingin from the left.

Comment: The movement of the ions must create a magnetic varying field as a result of the varying motion of the water. That varying magnetic field should theoretically induce a current in the two coils proportional to the rate of change of each field. I may be missing something. That last time I studied physics was in 1985.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the coils.  There may be a detectable current in each coil, but I think the power spent in generating new ions would not allow a net gain.. It would depend on the speed of the flow, but then if is is too fast not enough ions would be generated to replace the ones leaving. Calculations are needed.

Comment: I think that there are way too many variables for calculations. The water flow rate change, the density of ions in the water, the size of the plates, the coils, etc... Would be fun to experiment it somewhere. Give it to a physics student to make measurements and plots.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using more energy attracting the ions to the plates. And a fast flow will be needed to  create a large magnetic field and turbulence from this will make it difficult to get ions to stick on the plates.